# Adding an event notifier, preferred practice

Tags: plone, zope

I want to have an event fired on plone.app.blob.field.BlobField.index_html so that I can set up a subscriber to listen for it. The subscriber is no problem but obviously plone.app.blob is not my code, so notifying is a bit tricker. I have it monkey patched to do zope.event.notify(MyEvent(object)), but is that the best way to do this? I'm half expecting there to be some grok magic that lets me attach an event to a method.

Comment: What is your actual end goal? Firing an event whenever something is downloaded sounds like an unusual requirement.

Comment: I suggest that in any case, you likely do not want to write to the ZODB?  If you do not require access to the object/BLOB itself nor the ZODB, why not use one of the events/hooks already in ZPublisher (e.g. a handler for zope.publisher.interfaces.EndRequestEvent)?

Comment: The end goal is to log who downloaded a file and when, which I was planning to save in the var/log dir. I realize the Z2 logs show this but I thought this might give me more control over what information I want to log for this case, as well as separate it from everything else in that log. As a more general question, I am guessing trying to put a notifier in somewhere is frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to fork the project on Github and maintain and deploy a patched version using Mr. developer buildout tool.

Later, you can sign Plone contribution agreement and get your patch into a new release of plone.app.blob, so you don't need to have any patch magic anymore.